# Detect contour of part of circle with possible out of image center

Tags: python, opencv

I try to find circles and part-circles contours and have a problem with detection of circles where center is out of the image

```
gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv.blur(gray, (3,3))
gray = cv.Canny(gray, threshold1=75, threshold2=100)
```

[image: Result:]

After this I use HoughCircle function

```
circles = cv.HoughCircles(gray, cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 8,
                      param1=100, param2=30,
                      minRadius=50, maxRadius=700)
```

But contour that I want to find isn't in circles array, cause its center is out of the image.

How I can to detect this part of circle? Increase image size or smth like that?

UPD. I added borders to image:

```
  top = int(0.25 * src.shape[0])  # shape[0] = rows
  bottom = top
  left = int(0.25 * src.shape[1])  # shape[1] = cols
  right = left
  src = cv.copyMakeBorder(src, top, bottom, left, right, 
  cv.BORDER_CONSTANT,  None, [0,0,0])
```

But after this contour is not full: 
[image]

UPD.2 Image with part of circle:
[image]

Comment: can you pot the original image ?

Comment: I can't show original image, but I added simple example that have same behavior